# No Consumer RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, ttl

I am having a queue with no Consumer and per-message TTL defined.

What will happen when Max TTL message is at the head and it's TTL is not expired yet. Will other messages whose TTL is over but are in the queue behind the Head will move to the dead exchange queue or the original queue will be stuck and wait for Head TTL to expire and move to dead exchange queue ?

Answer (score 0):

When a message with TTL is at the head of the queue, the message will not be consumed by the consumer. Instead, the message will be moved to the dead-letter queue. Messages with expired TTL will stay in the queue as long as they have not reached the queue head.

Reference: https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#per-message-ttl-caveats